# Does the Samsung Galaxy Note 3 Support ANT+ WSN technology

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-3

Is the Note 3 compatible with ANT+ WSN technology?

Do all variants of Note 3 come with this or just a select few?

Also, do all networks use Note 3 with ANT+ WSN sets?

Answer (score 1):

[This is the current list of supported devices](http://www.thisisant.com/directory/filter/~/60/~/~/).  There look to be 3 top level variants for the Note 3.  If you select the model then press the more info link there is a list of the actual model numbers.

I am not sure if all the Note 3 variants are ANT capable but I think the majority are, you need to check the exact model number really to be sure.